# Probability zero vs impossible

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I understand that probability $0$ does not mean 'impossible' - because if we look for instance at a uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$ then while each of the singleton events $\{r\}$ for $0\leq r \leq 1$ has probability $0$, if we carried out the experiment then we would get exactly one of the numbers in $[0,1]$, and so these events are not actually impossible, even though they have probability $0$.

However, if we look at a distribution defined by a density function which is zero on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and non-zero on $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ (let's say with a continuous transition between them), then we know that for any $0\leq r\leq \frac{1}{2}$ the event $\{r\}$ is impossible, and for $\frac{1}{2}<r\leq 1$ the event is possible, yet still has probability $0$.

Both have probability $0$, but one of them is possible, and the other is not. Is there a definition that captures this distinction between the two cases?

Comment: That's because we can just obtain probabilities inside some interval. Without knowing how that density function is defined, there is no way of distinguish one $0$ from the other. You obtain a $0$ evaluating the probability of $\{r\}$ because $\{r\}$ is a set of "measure" $0$ (because it's a numerable set), and if you integrate any function under a measure $0$ set, you get $0$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a distribution defined by a density function"? The same function can be the density function of different random variables. So a density function does not define a random variable. What exactly is defined by the density function? ($+1$, by the way, it's an important conceptual question.)

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso So does that imply that as far as probability theory is concerned the distinction between the two types of probability $0$ events I described is inessential?

Comment: @joriki thanks, that's helpful. I'm afraid though now I've got myself confused about two things rather than just one.. is there a way to rephrase what I meant asking more precisely?

Comment: @Dan Yes, that's it.

Comment: This distinction often reminds me of the famous quote "shut up and calculate".  :)  For any event whose probability you care to calculate, the distinction will make absolutely no difference (because $a + 0 = a$).  And if you want to differentiate between $Unif([0,1])$ and $Unif((0,1))$... well they are different, but how can you tell by experimenting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, if we look at a distribution defined by a density function which is zero on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and non-zero on $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ (let's say with a continuous transition between them), then we know that for any $0\leq r\leq \frac{1}{2}$ the event $\{r\}$ is impossible, and for $\frac{1}{2}<r\leq 1$ the event is possible, yet still has probability $0$.

Why do you say that?  Consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  Let $r$ be any point of $[0,1]$.  Use this density:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,\qquad x <0 \text{ or }x=r \text{ or } x>1\\
1,\qquad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Of course this is still the same distribution: uniform on $[0,1]$.  But now your reasoning says $r$ is impossible.  So your notion of "impossible" depends not on the distribution itself, but in your choice of density function.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure I understand, the definition of $f(x)$ should be $0$ for $x=r$, correct?

Comment: Yes $x=r$, fixed.

Comment: So I think I get now that my notion of "impossible" depends not on the distribution itself. Something still confuses me though. I hope I'm not asking a silly question, but in the example I initially asked about, is it not a different situation, since there the density is $0$ on an interval?

Comment: Actually I think that joriki's answer provides an example for why it is actualy not a different situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

A real-valued [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) is a measurable function from the sample space to the real numbers. While a continuous random variable can be described by a density function and the density function contains all the information about probabilities of all events, that doesn’t mean that the density function fully defines the random variable. The difference you’re interested is a difference between random variables that doesn’t manifest in their density functions (and hence not in the probabilities of any events).

Consider the sample space $[0,1]^2$ (with the standard Lebesgue measure) and the random variable

$$
X((a,b))=
\begin{cases}
a&b\gt0\;,\\
a+1&b=0\;.
\end{cases}
$$

This random variable takes values on $[0,2]$ and has density $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ on $[1,2]$. Thus it has the same density as a random variable uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$; yet it can take values on $(1,2]$ whereas the latter can’t.

Thus, whether the event of a random variable taking a certain value is possible is determined simply by whether any element of the sample space is mapped to that value; and this need not be reflected in the density (and thus cannot be determined from the density alone).

Comment: OK, I think it is starting to become clearer to me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answers, one major sticking point is in the mathematical definition of "impossible".

If you view a random variable as a measurable function
$$
\begin{align*}
X: \Omega &\to [0, 1] \\
\omega &\mapsto X(\omega)
\end{align*}
$$
taking elements $\omega$ of some sample space $\Omega$ (i.e. events) to a real number $X(\omega)$ (the probability of that event happening), one reasonable definition is

$$
\text{An event } \omega \text{ is } \textbf{possible} \iff \omega \in \Omega
$$

Note that you can still have $X(\omega) = 0$, i.e. $\omega$ occurs with probability zero. Impossible events are then just those events *not* in the domain of $X$.